# if json_encode a string contains (&quot;) in phtml, the browser will change it's construction，how to prevent it?

Tags: jquery, json, php

php：5.3.3

jquery:1.7.2

here is the way we use to send the value from php to jquery.

1. get the escaped string.

`$a = '&quot;xxxxx'; $b = json_encode($a);`

1. and now, $b is '"xxxxx';
2. put $a in phtml.

   php:     `$this->view->b = $b;`

   phtml:    `<div id='my_data' style='display:none;'><?php echo $this->b;?></div>`

so in the phtml， the string is

`<div id='my_data' style='display:none'>"&quot;xxxxx"</div>`

but, when the the string show in browser, it will become ""xxxxx"。And when we use $.parseJSON($("#my_data").text());. JQuery will throw an exception, because ""xxxxx" is not a JSON string.

so， how to resole this ?

or any other ways to send an escaped string from php to JQuery.

thank u all.

Comment: The same way you would prevent a double quote in an HTML tag attribute from breaking up the parser... `htmlspecialchars($whatever_input, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8')`. However, I'd question whether you're doing the right thing by putting JSON into your document like this in the first place.

Comment: yes, i did. I have use `htmlspecialchars($whatever_input, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8')` to change escaped the string , so i can get the "&quot;xxxxx". but when i put the string in html tags, it will become ""xxxxx" and breaking up the parser :(